# highlighting cells which contain out of sequence invoice numbers in excel

Tags: excel

Hi I am trying to highlight out of sequence invoice numbers in excel.

My Column B shows invoice numbers. Usually the invoice numbers contain 2 letters and 6 numbers such as AA123456. I want to highlight the cells which does not fit this criteria.

Please help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So, it sounds like it's more of an issue of matching a pattern for each invoice, than the overall sequence of the invoices in column B. I'd take a look at the of the `IF`, `LEN` `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `ISNUMBER` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code checks for 3 criteria: If the value length is 8, if the last 6 characters are numbers and if the first 2 characters are text. Then changes the cell color to red. Just change the search range to the desired. Hope this fits for you.

```
Sub check()
    Dim cell, searchRng As Range
    Set searchRng = Range("b1:b10")
    For Each cell In searchRng.Cells
        If Not Len(cell) = 8 Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            GoTo iteration:
        End If
        If Not IsNumeric(Right(cell.Value, 6)) Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            GoTo iteration:
        End If
        If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Left(cell.Value, 2)) Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            GoTo iteration:
        End If
iteration:
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitris. Actually it is highlighting all the correct invoice numbers. Is there a way to highlight the wrong invoice numbers for example those one missing a letter or number when inputted?

Comment: I didn't get it in the first place but now I've corrected the code. I would like to suggest you though, if you have a lot of values to check, between the 3 IFs, choose to write first the most likely to happen.

Comment: Every time one of the IFs is executed, the code after it doesn't. So if you write first the most common case, you save executing code and the sub will be executed faster. I hope I've made a point.